# How does System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Disconnect disconnect from the socket?

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, winsock, detours

My DLL gets injected into a program and then hooks to `connect`, `send`, `recv` and `closesocket` functions using Detours. The point is to stop the program from connecting to some server and instead communicate with my DLL directly.

My `recv` function uses an infinite loop, just waiting for any data to send to the program. When `closesocket` is called that loop is broken and everything works fine.

But there's one program written in C# that just hangs when I close it. Its error log says:

> SocketException: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Disconnect (Boolean reuseSocket) [0x00000] in :0

The exception is expected since the socket never connects to anything. But is there any workaround for this? What does `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Disconnect` call under the hood? What other function do I need to hook to detect that?

I've tried hooking to `shutdown`, `setsockopt`, `WSACancelBlockingCall`, `WSACleanup`, `WSASend`, `WSASendDisconnect`, `WSASendMsg`, `WSASendTo`, `WSARecv`, `WSARecvDisconnect` and `WSARecvFrom`. None of them get called.

Comment: Use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to see the status of the connection.  You may see a Timed-Wait status which means both ends of the connection attempted to close at same time.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the connection.  A [FIN] means one side of the connection started to close connection.  TCP is reliable the every actions get an ACK from other end.  When both ends try to close at same time an ACK is missing and the status goes to Timed-Wait.

Comment: There never is any real connection. My `connect` function just saves the `SOCKET` value and returns success. It never calls the real `connect`. Then `send`, `recv` and `closesocket` compare that value to know if it's my socket or not.

Comment: The disconnect is being done at the transport layer in the Network Interface.

Comment: Fine. Just checked. There's noting about my connection in netstat and there's nothing in WireShark. I had to use RawCap to capture packets because the connection is on the loopback interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Disconnect` calls [`DisconnectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms737757(v=vs.85)). And as the remarks say:

> **Note**  The function pointer for the **DisconnectEx** function must be obtained at run time by making a call to the [**WSAIoctl**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaioctl) function with the **SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER** opcode specified. The input buffer passed to the **WSAIoctl** function must contain **WSAID_DISCONNECTEX**, a globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value identifies the DisconnectEx extension function. On success, the output returned by the WSAIoctl function contains a pointer to the **DisconnectEx** function. The **WSAID_DISCONNECTEX** GUID is defined in the *Mswsock.h* header file.

So if you want to do what I did you have to:

1. hook to [`WSAIoctl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaioctl)
2. check if `dwIoControlCode` is `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER`
3. check if `lpvInBuffer` is `WSAID_DISCONNECTEX`:

```cpp
IsEqualGUID(*((GUID*)lpvInBuffer), WSAID_DISCONNECTEX)
```

4. store the address to the real `DisconnectEx` somewhere

```cpp
LPFN_DISCONNECTEX Real_DisconnectEx = NULL;
(...)
Real_DisconnectEx = *((LPFN_DISCONNECTEX*)lpvOutBuffer);
```

5. return the address to your function

```cpp
*((LPFN_DISCONNECTEX*)lpvOutBuffer) = &Mine_DisconnectEx;
```